# utility function for nominal attributes

Tags: functions, utility

I'm working in a decision making topic where a product (e.g., a hotel) is described by some attributes, that is: $p=(p_1,\ldots,p_n)$. An attribute $p_i$ can either be numeric (e.g., the room average price), ordinal (e.g., the hotel category: $1\star,\ldots,5\star$) or nominal (e.g., the room color: red, green, blue).

We compute the utility of a product $p$ as a weighted sum of partial utilities $f_i(x)$, that is: $Util(p)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}w_i \times f_i(p_i)$. Here $f_i(p_i)$ is a value function or partial utility defined on the $ith$ product attribute.

I'm looking for a formal partial utility definition $f_i(x)$ for the case of a nominal attribute. There are several examples in the case of numeric and ordinal attributes. 
The problem with nominal attributes is that no preference order on the attribute values is known in advance. This is not the case of numeric or ordinal attribute values, where for example we know that $1\star < \ldots < 5\star$.

I'm not considering the case when the utility of every single nominal value is manually defined (e.g., $f_i(x_1)=v_1,\ldots,f_i(x_k)=v_k$, where $x_t$, $t=1\dots k$ are the different nominal attribute values). I'm looking for a general function definition. 
I have looked at some related information in books, papers, etc., but nothing useful has been found so far.

Any help will be really appreciated, thanks in advance.
Harold

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. In this case you might also want to specify what you mean by a "nominal attribute".

Comment: Thank you for your advices Martin. I have edited my question. I hope it is clear now.

Comment: Much clearer, but you should specify the properties that you want your function to satisfy. As it stands I can give you a formal definition : $f_i$ is any function from the set of nominal attributes to the set of real numbers. Or else, if by formal you mean "explicit, $f_i$ =[sum of the alphabetic order of the letters in the name of the nominal attribute]. But I guess that's not very satisfactory. Do you have information on preferences and you want your utility function to represent those preferences?

Comment: I'm trying to infer user preferences by observing the user reaction to some available options. For example, consider a scenario where a user is searching in a car catalogue in order to make a decision on what car to buy. A car is represented by 3 probably conflicting attributes: car=(price, color, engine). For example, imagine these cars are presented to the user.

$c1: (90, blue, 8c)$; $c2: (60, green, 6c)$; $c3: (20, red, 4c)$.

Comment: I can infer some preferences on the color attribute after the user selection. For instance, if the user selects the car c2, I can infer that he prefers the green color, but I cannot say anything about the other options (green and red).

In my case, I'm considering a partial utility function for a nominal attribute like this one:

$f_{z_i}(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{lll}
 1   & \mbox{if} & x = z_i \\
 a_x & \mbox{if} & x \neq z_i
\end{array}
\right.$

Comment: Here $z_i$ is the user preferred value on the attribute $i$. $0 \leq a_x < 1$ represents the partial utility value assigned to the value x. 
My problem is that, so far, I have no idea on how to define $a_x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if I understand you right, your problem is the estimation of a discrete choice model :  you want to find the specification of the utility function that matches best the data you have on people's choices.

Essentially, this is a question of applied statistics, much more than a mathematical one. I think your question should be migrated to http://stats.stackexchange.com. You will probably get better answers there : they already have [a set of question about the estimation of discrete choice models](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=discrete%20choice).

There are different possible ways to tackle your problem. To witness the breath of approaches, have a look at the results of a google search for "estimation of discrete choice models", e.g.

http://biogeme.epfl.ch/v18/tutorialv18.pdf
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ok534E1lf_k
http://statisticalinnovations.com/products/choice_tutorial1.pdf

Your choice should depend on the data you have, the assumptions you are ready to make, the time you can put into conducting the analysis and the level of sophistication you are able to deal with.